# Why is the export button on business network card greyed out?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been following the hyperledger composer tutorial on creating business network cards . In the tutorial it is shown that after creating the card it can then be exported. But when I try to export the business network card it is greyed out and cannot be exported.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you are either using the Online Playground, or using a locally installed Playground but using the **Connection: Web Browser**.

The 'Web Browser' connection uses a simulated Fabric in the browser localstorage, and the cards are not suitable for export.  (This simulated Fabric is really fast for developing a model with lots of updates but has its limitations.)

If you are using locally installed Playground to connect to a local FAbric, you should be able to see **Connection: hlfv1** and you should be able to export cards from there.